# Downloading recent GRACE data

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, data, satellite

I have been doing GRACE data processing in GEE, but from what I can tell - only the first mission's data (dating from 2002/04 to 2017/01) is accessible through the library for import.

Can I access more recent data from the GRACE-FO mission for analysis in GEE?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GRACE-FO has [already been requested](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139467017).

I found that by [searching for "GRACE"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:1161680%20GRACE) in the issue tracker that is linked from the Code Editor's Feedback menu in the top right. (These links aren't publicly accessible, but access to the issue tracker is automatically granted to any account signed up for Earth Engine, if I remember correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the GRACE-FO Mascon data is not available but I would like to drop a github repo that will help you to convert GRACE-FO measurement from Center for Space Research (CSR) to geotiff, and ingest into Earth Engine as raster image assets, which you can further use for your analysis.